# Rails: Select helpers are sending get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

i'm currently getting an issue with this simple code :

```
=form_tag payments_path, :method => :post, :id => "braintree-payment-form" do

  = select_month(14, :use_month_numbers => true)

  = select_year(Time.now.year, :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year + 10)
```

In fact, when i select a value in one of the two selects above, it automatically to a get request on the current URL with the parameter i selected

exemple: if i click on 2013 in select_year it lead to /payments/2013

Anyone have a clue about it? It's exetremely annoying, i ran through this issue previouly and couldn't have found a proper solution.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

When i put these two selects out of the form tag, il also redirect me to /payment/selected_value, i really don't understand why it does that? 
I tried put a e.preventDefault() in JS on the change of the selects but it has no effect

Comment: there is probably some javascript involved! go to your project and do a `grep -r "braintree-payment-form" .` is there any .js or .coffee file that uses this id? you can also open your browsers development console, look at the network tab and see who is doing the request.

Comment: It's not that i guess because if i change the name  and the id of the selects it still does that

Comment: there might be some generic event-handler on select fields or forms. in chrome you can have a look at each html element and the events that are bound to them. this might help you identifying the root of the problem.

Comment: Ok i found the problem, it was as you guessed some random wild JS function sneakly hidden in my JS files

Comment: if you found some comments helpful, you can mark them so. this might be useful for others looking at your question. it's also a good thing to write an answer and accept it yourself so that no one has to worry about this one any longer.